# jQuery closest('tr') not working in iOS

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios

I have the following code

```
fnDrawCallback: function() {
    $("#rqTable tbody tr td .fa-edit").closest('td').on('click', function() {
        // log for testing
        console.log(this);
        console.log(this.closest('tr'));
        console.log(this.closest('tr').id);
    });
}
```

It works as expected in IE, Chrome, Firefox, Andriod but not in Safari or on an iPhone.

this is a screen shot of the console in firefox
[image]

thisis a screen shot of the console in safari 
[image]

Is there something I should be doing different to account for the iOS difference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As `closest()` is a jQuery function you need to use it with jQuery object. Similarly use `.prop()` to get it any property.

`this` refers to native DOM element, which doesn't have the above method. use the with jQuery object.

```
$(this).closest('tr').prop('id');
// $(this).closest('tr').prop('id'); //OR you can also use .attr()
```

Comment: That might solve his problem.  But why is it working elsewhere?

Comment: This did fix the issue but I don't know why then it worked in all the other browsers?

Comment: @user1167442, I was away, However In my experience it should not be working elsewhere too

Comment: I agree. The only exception I can think of is in a jQuery element plugin where `this` inherits jQuery.  His dev console screenshots say otherwise though